# PHP split name and phone number (text and number)

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm using `preg_split` to separate text and phone number from a string.

My testing cases below:

```php
$string_one = "1. Maria +60136777000";
$string_two = "2. Rahul Khan 0146067705";
$string_three = "Johny +6013699900";
$string_four = "Henry 01363456900";
```

And this is my function:

```php
function split_them($str) {
    return preg_split("/(\D)(\d)/", $str);
}
```

When I use the function like this, phone number is always incomplete:

```php
// string_one
echo "<pre>";
print_r(split_them($string_one));
echo "</pre>";

// output
array(2
0   =>  1. Maria 
1   =>  0136777000 // <--- number is incomplete
)

// string_two
echo "<pre>";
print_r(split_them($string_two));
echo "</pre>";

// output
array(2
0   =>  2. Rahul Khan
1   =>  146067705 // <--- number is incomplete
)

// string_three
echo "<pre>";
print_r(split_them($string_three));
echo "</pre>";

// output
array(2
0   =>  Johny
1   =>  013699900 // <--- number is incomplete
)

// string_four
echo "<pre>";
print_r(split_them($string_four));
echo "</pre>";

// output
array(2
0   =>  Henry
1   =>  1363456900 // <--- number is incomplete
)
```

Perhaps my regex is incorrect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following `preg_split` code:

```
preg_split('~\s+(?=\+?\d+$)~', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/foKvJJ/3).

It splits a string at the last 1+ whitespaces (`\s+`) that are followed with an optional `+` (`\+?`) and 1+ digits (`\d+`) at the end of the string (`$`).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NrljGi):

```
$re = '/\s+(?=\+?\d+$)/';
$strs = ['Johny +6013699900','2. Rahul Khan 0146067705','Johny +6013699900','Henry 01363456900'];
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    print_r(preg_split($re, $s));
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Johny
    [1] => +6013699900
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2. Rahul Khan
    [1] => 0146067705
)
Array
(
    [0] => Johny
    [1] => +6013699900
)
Array
(
    [0] => Henry
    [1] => 01363456900
)
```

Answer (score 1):

or like this:

```
function split_them($str) {
    preg_match("/(.+)\s+(.?\d{5,})/", $str, $matches);
    array_shift($matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

Output is:

> Array (
>       [0] => 1. Maria
>       [1] => +60136777000 )
>
> Array (
>       [0] => 2. Rahul Khan
>       [1] => 0146067705 )
>
> Array (
>       [0] => Johny
>       [1] => +6013699900 )
>
> Array (
>       [0] => Hitler
>       [1] => 01363456900 )

Comment: Thank you so much sir.. Work perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

- try this $iparr = split ("/+/", $ip);  print "$iparr[0]";

Answer (score -1):

Try split them by string with explode() PHP function.
Example

```
$foo = "one two three";

print_r(explode(" ", $foo));

//Output
array (
0 => 'one',
1 => 'two',
2 => 'three'
)
```